# create and call function from python

Tags: python

### Here is small module called smbk.py

```
def sumtwo(x,y):

    z = x + y
    return z


def multtwo(a,b):

    c = a - b
    return c
```

---

I am calling function below.

```
import smbk

print smbk.multtwo(2,3)
```

I get following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'multtwo'
```

Comment: what is the output of `dir(smbk)`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'smbk' is not defined

Comment: @JayaSudha `import smbk; dir(smbk)` .

Comment: I'd guess that you've made a "stupid" error (ie failed to save smbk.py, importing another version of it or simply mistyped something) . Try to check `smbk` and the contents of it, fx by inserting `print smbk, dir(smbk)` between the `import` and the `print` in the second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both files in the same dir.

Or if you use python shell, you need to call python from the same dir where smbk.py exists.

Comment: This may only be partly the case, if `smbk.py` did not exist in the python path, they would be getting an ImportError, not the current one.

Comment: The other part of the case could be that another `smbk.py` do exist in the python path (or even before the intended). That's why it could be useful to do `print smbk` to check which source is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use smbk?There is no need for that.You can call the function like this:

```
def sumtwo(x,y):
    z=x+y
    return z
z=sumtwo(2,3)
print(z)
```

Comment: There's no reason to question the choice of putting the functions in separate modules. He might for example want to use these functions in two different programs.